# How do I ensure my AJAX calls are from the same domain and port to avaoid access-control-allow-origin header issues?

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, endpoint

I've read almost everything I can find on Access-Control-Allow-Origin stuff, and I seem to not be able to ensure this AJAX request is coming from the same port number and domain as the server. This is my javascript:

```js
alert('JS is linked to page!');

function Article(id = 1, title = "", authors="", content = "", genre = "", date = 1497484623) {
    console.log("JavaScript file loaded successfully");
    var self = this;
    self.Id = id;
    self.Title = title;
    self.Authors = authors;
    self.Content = content;
    self.Genre = genre;
    self.Date = date;
    self.Save = function() {
        var settings = {
            url: 'http://localhost/articles/addArticle',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
              beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            }
        };
        var myData = {
   "Id" : self.Id,
            "Title": self.Title,
            "Authors": self.Authors,
            "Content": self.Content,
            "Genre": self.Genre,
            "Date": self.Date
        };
        settings.data = myData;
 
        $.ajax(settings).done(function(article) {
         var myArticle = new Article(article.Id, article.Title, article.Authors,
                article.Content, article.Genre, article.Date);
        });
    };
}



function addArticle(Article) {
    alert('addArticle Activated');
    var settings = {
        url: 'http://localhost/articles/addArticle',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            }
    };
    var myData = {  
  "Title": Article.Title,     
  "Authors" : Article.Authors,
  "Content": Article.Content,
  "Genre" : Article.Genre,
  "Date": Article.Date 
    };
    settings.data = myData;
 
    $.ajax(settings).done(function(Article) {
        var myArticle = new Article(article.Id, article.Title, article.Authors, article.Content,
            article.Genre, article.Date);
        console.log("Article Created");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

 
    $(document).on("submit", "#add-article", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            alert('submit Activated');
        var title, authors, genre, content;
        title = $("#Title").val();
        director = $("#Authors").val();
        rating = $("#Genre").val();
        notes = $("#Content").val();
        var myArticle = new Article(0, title, authors, genre, content, 1497484623);
        alert(myArticle.Title);
        addArticle(myArticle);
        $("#add-article")[0].reset();
        $("#title").focus();
 
    });

});
```

The thing is that I have been able to successfully populate my database with postman by hitting this endpoint:

> http://localhost:8080/articles/addArticle

Now I understand that:

> http://localhost:8080/articles/addArticle

is different from

> http://localhost/articles/addArticle

...but how do I fix it? When I try putting ":8080" in the url for the javascript, it throws a 404 **as well** as the access-control-Allow-Origin error.

This is my java controller for the endpoint if anyone wants to see:

```js
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/articles")
public class ArticleController {

 private ArticleRepo articleRepo;

 @Autowired
 public ArticleController(ArticleRepo articleRepo) {
  this.articleRepo = articleRepo;
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/findall", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 @ResponseBody
 public List<Article> findall() {
  return articleRepo.findAll();
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/addArticle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public Article addArticle(@RequestBody Article newArticle) {
  articleRepo.save(newArticle);
  return newArticle;
 }
}
```

**What I've tried**

- I can't specify a port for an AJAX request as far as I know, since it violates the same origin policy
- I can't use JSONP because I'm trying to populate data into mongodb instead of just using Get requests
- I tried looking into Spring Forms, but I'm not sure that I want to side-step the issue as opposed to figuring out the right way to do it
- I tried using CORS but couldn't get it to work and none of the examples on StackOverflow were clear enough for me to understand
- I tried trying to ensure everything was from the same domain by including the port number in the request mapping in my controller, but that doesn't seem to work (or I'm not doing it correctly)
- I've found other ways to insert data into mongo right through javascript, but they end up skipping the endpoints and don't allow me to sanitize data

I'm convinced there's a way to do this because I've done it before - all I have to do is ensure the requests are coming from the same domain and port, but I cannot figure out how. I've been wrestling with this since Monday, so if someone can help me out I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Website url is `http://localhost`?

Comment: Is the site you're making this request from running off `http://localhost`? Have you tried using relative path (`url: 'articles/addArticle'`)?

Comment: @James 
Uh, localhost is how you run stuff locally off your computer. Again, as indicated in the question, I've successfully hit this endpoint with postman and populated my mongo collection with data this way. It just doesn't seem to like it from the front end because it's interpreting it as if it's coming from a different domain.

Comment: @Arman 
I can try using a relative path but since it's being hosted locally, localhost is the answer as far as I can tell. I've had this work successfully with other programs in the past.